# IS there any way so that i can apply animations on charts using AChartEngine

Tags: android, animation, charts, achartengine

I'm using AchartEngine to create charts in android. But not able to show animations. For example : in pies chart i want initial rotations. In bar chart i want bar should grow from top to bottom. 
Or is there any API or library which helps to build animated charts in android.

Please suggests or give any sample.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You just need to modify the property you want to be modified and then call `mChartView.repaint();`

Comment: See this: https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/XYChartBuilder.java